# If I have Jupyter, how does Sublime Text fit into workflow?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, sublimetext

I have always used RStudio but recently started working in a shop that uses python. We have Jupyter and Sublime Text. I haven't figured out what Sublime Text adds to the workflow if I can use Jupyter. Is there something specific that Sublime does better than coding directly in Jupyter?

I am not sure how the two fit together when I can use the kernels in a workspace/notebooks to write.

Edit for clarity: I write python code to analyze data and json to hold dictionaries to decode said data. Right now I feel like I'm able to do all that in Jupyter but keep hearing that Sublime Text is useful for python and json. I'm not looking for opinions, by rather uses for Sublime Text in conjunction with Jupyter notebooks. I feel like I'm missing a piece of useful things that Sublime Text can do.

Comment: Since Jupyter is a notebook style and Sublime builds and runs as a script, I use the prior for exploring (manipulating data, designing a function), and the latter for integrating (putting all the functions together and making them go). That's my $0.02.

Comment: one does not replace the other. To provide a valid answer to your question you have to fully understand your workflow first. Please elaborate so we know wheter the question is too broad or primarily opinion based.